# Symfony: How do I annotate entity properties that are objects to get Doctrine to store a foreign key?

Tags: symfony, annotations, doctrine-orm

I'm still getting to grips with Symfony and Doctine and I appreciate this might sound overly simple.

I have at present two basic entities: `WebSite` (having `id` and `canonicalUrl` properties) and `Job` which has, as one property, a `WebSite`.

A `Job` has one `WebSite`; a `WebSite` can be referenced by many `Job`s. Both are under the same namespace.

Relevant here is the `Job` entity:

```
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Job
{
    /**
     * 
     * @var integer
     * 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     *
     * @var WebSite
     */
    protected $website;
}
```

In database terms, a persisted `Job` should be storing the `id` of the relevant `WebSite`.

Without any changes to the above, calling `php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff` generates a new migration for a table named `Job` with a single `id` field.

How do I annotate `Job::website` such that Doctrine knows to create an integer field and to get the value as the `id` of the `Website` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must explicitly define the relationship. The shortest would be

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Job
{
    /**
     * @var WebSite
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Website")
     */
    protected $website;
}
```

However, should you find yourself wanting to tweak the relationship to better suit your needs, have a look at the [annotation reference](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html) ([`ManyToOne`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-manytoone) and [`JoinColumn`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn) for this particular case). There's also quite a comprehensive article about [association mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html), which you might find interesting.